# Android how to databind to parent class fields

Tags: android, data-binding

I have a class

```
 abstract class A extends BaseObservable{
 private String x;
 @Bindable
 public String getX(){
  return x;
}
public void setX(String val)
 {
    x=val;
    notifychange();
 }
}

public class B extends A{
 private int y;
 ....
}
```

Now in Layout file

....
Now I want to bind a text view to x which is in base class.

Tried casting it
    (A)(myvar).x

but IDE is giving error.

Pl let me know how can I do it without overriding the base class fields in child class as I have many child classes derived from base.

Answer (score -1):

Your type cast is wrong, you're trying to cast the result of `myVar.x` (a String) to class A, which isn't possible. Your cast should be like `((A)myVar).x`.

Anyways, i don't think your problem lies with the cast, since it shouldn't be needed at all as class A inherits all of class B's properties.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for answering. Your answer seems plausible, but would benefit from some explanation of the details of casting in this specific way and why that helps. "precedence" might be a useful keyword.